# Can't start Monero RPC Node

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, rpc

I'm trying to start an RPC node but the command below has only works once

```
monero-wallet-rpc --rpc-bind-port 18081 --wallet-file monero-pool --prompt-for-password --daemon-address 127.0.0.1:18089 --untrusted-daemon --disable-rpc-login --rpc-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --confirm-external-bind
```

I start the daemon with the following command:

```
./monerod --public-node --p2p-bind-ip=0.0.0.0 --p2p-bind-port=18080 --rpc-bind-ip=0.0.0.0 --rpc-bind-port=18081 --rpc-restricted-bind-ip=0.0.0.0 --rpc-restricted-bind-port=18089 --confirm-external-bind --detach
```

Once I enter the RPC command I need to enter my password and everything looks fine except after a couple of seconds I get:

```
2023-09-18 08:45:11.286 F Error starting server: Failed to bind IPv4 (set to required)
2023-09-18 08:45:11.286 E Failed to initialize wallet RPC server
```

I tried rebooting the VPS and the command `killall monerod`. I can confirm that there is no monerod running after the `killall` command. But the RPC node won't start up

It feels like I'm missing something stupid but I'm not sure what.

I can confirm my daemon is running because I can connect my monero-wallet-gui with the remote node and `./monerod status` is returning the following:

```
Height: 2976766/2976766 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 2.19 GH/s, v16, 12(out)+27(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 15m 56s
```

`ps -e | grep monero` gives me:
   `1131 ?        00:00:38 monerod` so the rpc node is not running as a stale process

Comment: it doesn't mather if I trie `monero-wallet-rpc` or `./monero-wallet-rpc`, same error

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `--rpc-bind-port=18081` on both daemon *and* wallet RPC. Use different ports.

You can't ask two completely separate processes to listen on the *same* port.